# quartz - fixed interval with initial delay

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

On spring scheduler, this is what I wanted to achieved:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 5000)
```

I'm moving to quartz, and I cannot seem to find the equivalent API for the initial delay.

```
TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMilliseconds(5000));
```

Any ideas how I can add the delay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`TriggerBuilder::startAt`](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html#startAt(java.util.Date))

```java
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
  .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMilliseconds(5000))
  .startAt(nowPlusDelay(5_000))
.build();
```

Where `nowPlusDelay(int)` returns a `Date`.